# What's the right way to get outputs in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, xbuild

What's the right way for getting the outputs from CallTarget in msbuild? I tried doing something like this (see `CoreOutput` and `EnumsOutput` in `CallTarget`):

```
<Target Name="TerrainEngine" Outputs="$(GeneratedAssembly)">

  <Message Text="Core0: $(CoreOutput)" />
  <Message Text="Enum0: $(EnumsOutput)" />

  <CallTarget Targets="Core" >
    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" PropertyName="CoreOutput"/>
  </CallTarget>

  <Message Text="Core1: $(CoreOutput)" />
  <Message Text="Enum1: $(EnumsOutput)" />

  <CallTarget Targets="Enums" >
    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" PropertyName="EnumsOutput"/>
  </CallTarget>

  <Message Text="Core2: $(CoreOutput)" />
  <Message Text="Enum2: $(EnumsOutput)" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <RefsList Include="$(CoreOutput)" />
    <RefsList Include="$(EnumsOutput)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Refs>@(RefsList)</Refs>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="ModuleDir!!!!: $(Refs)" />

  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="CreateModule"
      Properties="ModuleDir=BigMaps;
      RefAssemblies=$(UnityLibsPath)/UnityEngine.dll;
      RefModules=$Refs">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" PropertyName="GeneratedAssembly"/>
  </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

For some reason the second CallTarget invalidates both variables. I get output like this:

```
Core0:
Enum0:
Core1: modules/Core.mobule
Enum1:
Core2: 
Enum2: modules/Enums.mobule
```

As far I understand this is due to some bug in msbuild logic (that's the impression that I've got from reading about it online).

Can you tell me how to solve it?

I've read that I should use `DependsOnTargets` instead, but I couldn't really figure out how to take the outputs from these then. Is that possible?

Comment: This is likely not a bug pre se, rather a feature, just because of the way msbuild evaluation works. Anyway: please provide a small (get rid of all the unneeded stuff) self-contained sample reproducing the issue (what are the enums and core targets?) and clearly describe what you want the end result to be